# Items not selected when using custom MultipleChoiceField

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms, multiple-select

I am using a custom `MultipleChoiceField`, in order to display user's full names instead of their logins.

I customized the way items are displayed using the `choices` attribute of MultipleChoiceField:

```
assignees = MultipleChoiceField(choices=[(user.id, user.get_full_name() or user.username) for user in User.objects.all()])
```

Users names are correctly displayed, but **the problem is** that on edition (i.e. where the Form is given an instance of `Story` with existing assigned users), the corresponding `<option>` are not selected...

I tried using the `initial` keyword but that didn't helped.

```
self.fields['assignees'] = MultipleChoiceField(choices=[(user.id, user.get_full_name() or user.username) for user in User.objects.all()],
                                    initial=[user.id for user in self.instance.assignees])
```

---

> models.py

```
class Story(BaseModel):
    assignees = models.ManyToManyField(User, 
                                       blank=True,
                                       related_name="assigned")
```

> forms.py

```
class StoryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    assignees = MultipleChoiceField(choices=[(user.id, user.get_full_name() or user.username) for user in User.objects.all()])
```

> views.py

```
def story_edit(request, story_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        story = get_object_or_404(Story, id=story_id)
        form = StoryForm(request.POST, instance=story)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
        story = get_object_or_404(Story, id=story_id)
        form = StoryForm(instance=story)

    return render(request, 'story_form.html', {'form': form})
```

> story_form.html

```
<p>
    {{ form.assignees.errors }}
    {{ form.assignees }}
</p>
```

Comment: during form errors ??

Comment: Sorry? I don't understand